# Recursion upside down triangle

Tags: python, recursion

I'm supposed to create a recursive statement that if first calls triangle(n) it returns

```
'******\n *****\n ****\n ***\n **\n *'
```

This above is called for triangle(6) and if I print(triangle(6)) it returns below.

```
******
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *
```

Then I must create another code recursive_triangle(x, n) that returns a string with the LAST x lines of a right triangle of base and height n. For example if I did recursive_triangle(3, 6) it returns

```
'   ***\n    **\n     *'
```

and if i print it should returns

```
***
 ** 
  *
```

So far my code is

```
#### DO NOT modify the triangle(n) function in any way! 
def triangle(n):
    return recursive_triangle(n, n)
###################


def recursive_triangle(k, n=0):
    '''
    Takes two integers k and n
    >>> recursive_triangle(2,4)
    '  **\\n   *'
    >>> print(recursive_triangle(2,4))
      **
       *
    >>> triangle(4)
    '****\\n ***\\n  **\\n   *'
    >>> print(triangle(4))
    ****
     ***
      **
       *
'''
    # --- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    if n == 1:
        return "*"


    else:
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            return ("*" *n) + "\n" + (' ' * i) + triangle (n - 1)
```

for print(triangle(4)) this is what i got

```
****
 ***
 **
 *
```

How do I modify the code to get the output above?

Comment: Your first two "code" boxes don't match: the string you give at the top matches your actual output, not the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion case is ill-formed:

```
else:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        return ("*" *n) + "\n" + (' ' * i) + triangle (n - 1)
```

First of all, this code returns after a single iteration: `return` ends your function instance, so `i` never gets to a value of 2.  You need to do something simple, and then recur on a simpler case to handle the rest.

Next, `triangle` exists only to call `recursive_triangle`.  Then, `recursive_triangle` needs to call *itself*, not loop back to `triangle`.

Finally, note that `recursive_triangle` utterly ignores the parameter `k`.  This value is critical to determine where in the line to place the asterisks.

Each instance of `recursive_triangle` should produce a single line of the triangle -- you have that correct -- and then concatenate that line with the remainder of the triangle, returning that concatenated whole to the instance that called it.  You'll want something roughly like:

```
else:
    line = ... # build a line of k-n spaces and n asterisks
    return line + recursive_triangle(k, n-1)
```

Can you take it from there?  Among other things, remember to insert a few useful `print` commands to trace your execution flow and the values you generate.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there are better ways to achieve this.
However, if you really want to go this way, the following code can fix the spacing issues.

```
#### DO NOT modify the triangle(n) function in any way! 
def triangle(n):
    return recursive_triangle(n, n)
###################


def recursive_triangle(k, n=0):
    '''
    Takes two integers k and n
    >>> recursive_triangle(2,4)
    '  **\\n   *'
    >>> print(recursive_triangle(2,4))
      **
       *
    >>> triangle(4)
    '****\\n ***\\n  **\\n   *'
    >>> print(triangle(4))
    ****
     ***
      **
       *
'''
    # --- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    if n == 1:
        return "*"


    else:
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            return ("*" *n) + "\n" + (' ' * i) + triangle (n - 1).replace("\n", "\n ")
```

which gives you

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
```

in Python 3.6.5.

Answer (score -1):

You can count the row with `r` and use a secondary parameter to count the spaces, `s`

```
def triangle (r = 0, s = 0):
  if r is 0:
    return ""
  else:
    return (" " * s) + ("*" * r) + "\n" + triangle (r - 1, s + 1)

print (triangle(5))
# *****
#  ****
#   ***
#    **
#     *
```

Answer (score -1):

*code.py*:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


#### DO NOT modify the triangle(n) function in any way! 
def triangle(n):
    return recursive_triangle(n, n)
###################


def recursive_triangle(k, n=0):
    '''
    Takes two integers k and n
    >>> recursive_triangle(2,4)
    '  **\\n   *'
    >>> print(recursive_triangle(2,4))
      **
       *
    >>> triangle(4)
    '****\\n ***\\n  **\\n   *'
    >>> print(triangle(4))
    ****
     ***
      **
       *
    '''
    # --- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE

    if k == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return "\n".join(["".join([" " * (n - k), "*" * k]), recursive_triangle(k - 1, n)])
        #return " " * (n - k) + "*" * k + "\n" + recursive_triangle(k - 1, n)


def main():
    print("triangle(6):\n{:s}".format(triangle(6)))
    print("recursive_triangle(3, 6):\n{:s}".format(recursive_triangle(3, 6)))
    print("repr recursive_triangle(2, 4): {:s}".format(repr(recursive_triangle(2, 4))))
    print("repr triangle(4): {:s}".format(repr(triangle(4))))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- To make things simpler, you can look at `recursive_triangle(k, n)`'s argument meanings like:

  - *k*: Recursion step, and also the number of "*******" characters. Decrements with every recursive function call
  - *n*: 1<sup>st</sup> (longest) triangle line length (the number of *SPACE*s + *k*). Remains constant inside recursion
- Current line contains ***n - k*** *SPACE*s followed by ***k*** "*******" s (***n*** characters in total). Lines are joined together via [[Python 3]: str.**join**(*iterable*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (or "manually", in the  (next) commented line)
- The function calls itself until there are no more ***"*"*** characters (*k* becomes ***0***)

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q052652407>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> triangle(6):
> ******
>  *****
>   ****
>    ***
>     **
>      *
>
> recursive_triangle(3, 6):
>    ***
>     **
>      *
>
> repr recursive_triangle(2, 4): '  **\n   *\n'
> repr triangle(4): '****\n ***\n  **\n   *\n'
> ```